# Will ng2-bootstrap work with RC6?

Tags: ng2-bootstrap

Has anyone used ng2-bootstrap with RC6?

I do this in app.module (following the instructions on gitHub):

```
import {AlertModule} from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';
@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule, AlertModule],
    exports: [],
    providers: [],
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

I get an error at runtime:

> syntaxError: Unexpected token <

Comment: You can use an alternative that actually works with RC6: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/

Answer (score 0):

`syntaxError: Unexpected token <`

Means that system.js made a request for .js file and got html (404 or index.html) in response, you need to properly config system.js
or use webpack ;)

you can get more help in official slack channel https://www.hamsterpad.com/chat/ng2